# How can I programmatically get which application version is deployed to an Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to determine winch application version is deployed to the environment my code is running on.

I know that Elastic Beanstalk is tracking this as you can view it from:

**In Elastic Beanstalk Console:**

```
All Applications > [Application Name] -> Application versions
```

In the table displayed here, it shows the **Version Label**, and a list of which Environments it's **Deployed To**

[image]

Does anyone know how to query the EC2 container / EB from within the instance 
 / environment to get the Version Label of the currently deployed application version? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-status.html), you can use the eb cli command `eb status {environment-name}` which will give you an output that includes the `Deployed Version`:

```
$ eb status
Environment details for: tmp-dev
  Application name: tmp
  Region: us-west-2
  Deployed Version: None
  Environment ID: e-2cpfjbra9a
  Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running PHP 5.5
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: tmp-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2014-10-29 21:37:19.050000+00:00
  Status: Launching
  Health: Grey
```

Comment: You know, I searched everywhere for this... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 you can get the deployed application version label within the ec2 instance using

```
cat /var/elasticbeanstalk/healthd/latest.json | jq -r '.version_label'
```